# Amazon EC2 cloud hosting

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2, hosting

How do I host a http server at front, while multiple tomcat server behind it in EC2?

Do we need to do session and cookie management or does EC2 has it inbuild?

Can we stream images and static resources through some other server while dynamic content from tomcat?

Comment: this question is too broad. try to do a little bit more research on this subject before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Java support in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It handles the load balancing, auto scaling, metrics and deployment for you. Deploy your static assets to S3 + CloudFront instead of keeping them inside your application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to host a webserver in front and redirect requests to multiple tomcat servers in backend. Assuming you have webserver and multiple tomcat servers deployed over a EC2 and tomcat. Using ajp or mod_proxy or mod_jk, you can redirect requests hitting on your webserver to your backend tomcat servers.

By default, AWS does not provide cookie or session management. You can use AWS Elasticache for session management.

Yes, you can upload your images and other static content on Amazon S3 and deliver it from S3 itself or using CloudFront (CDN) while your dynamic requests are coming to your tomcat servers.

Your questions was too broad. If you provide more details, we can help more.

Thanks
Sanket